# ¿Cómo posicionar un sprite sobre fondo de capa div mediante css?

Tags: html, css, div

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Qué html y css necesito para configurar 3 capas div cada una con un logo de la imagen anterior (sprite)? El objetivo es que cada logo de red social esté en el fondo de una capa.

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida a SOes! Te recomiendo darte una vuelta por el [Tour de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para ver como funciona el sitio y así de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante leer [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para formular una pregunta de calidad y que esta sea bien recibida. ¿Que has intentando?

Comment: por favor, comparte el código donde quieres posicionarlo y trata de reformular la pregunta para que algún compañero pueda ayudarte en tu consulta. Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Para usar un sprite de html lo que se hace es definir el background-image de los elementos como a esa imagen.

Luego, para cada elemento por separado se fija el width y height (en casos como este en que no coincide en todos) y se usa el background-position para recortar la parte de la imágen que se desea.

He creado un ejemplo de esto con esa misma imagen que has puesto de sprite:

```css
.sprite {
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/XN0S1.png");
  display: inline-block;
}

.google-plus {
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
}

.facebook {
  width:63px;
  height: 28px;
  background-position: -36px 0px;
}

.twitter {
  width:63px;
  height: 28px;
  background-position: -98px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sprite google-plus" title="Google Plus"></div>
<div class="sprite facebook" title="Facebook"></div>
<div class="sprite twitter" title="Twitter"></div>
```

Le he puesto un `title` a cada div para que se vea en que div estás cuando el cursor está encima.

Comment: Me parece buena respuesta, pero podría aparecer en línea.

Comment: Una vez lo tienes en divs separados puedes hacer con ellos lo que quieras. Para eso puedes, por ejemplo, ponerles `display: inline-block` a esos divs por css y ya lo tienes. Si eso de aquí un rato cuando esté al pc actualizo la respuesta

Comment: que te parece si utilizo algo como float

Comment: También, las dos sirven. Y también se puede con flex, cualquier manera de alinear los divs te sirve. A mi para esto la opción de `inline-block` me gusta más pero no es la única opción. Si los haces float ten en cuenta que luego según como siga el código puede que te haga falta un`clear`

Comment: Ya está, le he podido poner el `inline-block` a `.sprite` que es lo que tienen en común los 3 divs, ahora aparecen en línea. A partir de saber usar los sprites para separar las partes el resto es conocer un poco los css y ser creativo.

Comment: Muy buen aporte. Gracias. Complemento con un poco de teoría: la propiedad display: inline-block;
en comparación con display: inline; tiene como principal diferencia que te permite establecer un ancho y una altura en el elemento.

Además, con display: inline-block, se respetan los márgenes / rellenos (margin/padding) superiores e inferiores, y con display: inline; no.

En comparación con display: block, la principal diferencia es que display: inline-block; no agrega un salto de línea después del elemento, por lo que el elemento puede sentarse junto a otros elementos.

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo muy bien que es lo que buscas. Si se trata de tener los 3 logos por separado cada uno en un DIV, lo primero que deberías hacer es partir esa ímagen en 3 imágenes separadas.

Si lo que quieres es determinar 3 enlaces diferentes en una misma imagen puedes utilizar la etiqueta TAG de HTML (https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp)

Comment: Gracias por el apoyo pero responder con solo enlaces se considera de baja calidad, lee [answer]